# How catch callback after new page was loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-endless-pagination

I use pagination on scroll by [Django EL(Endless) Pagination](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination) library in my project.

**Question:** Is there any way to catch callback that will fire at the end of the request cycle, after new items have been appended to the container?! I need to refresh one script which don't work for added items. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can attach callback after new page is fully loaded and inserted in the DOM. Just use `onCompleted` callback. If you want detail answer I will make it when you say so...

Comment: Hello, my friend! :) Please, can you show me some example for clarity.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I found solution. As you said it works with: `onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {/*code*/}`. Can you post your answer one more time. I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [onCompleted](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/javascript.html#attaching-callbacks) callback to perform some action after the new page is fully loaded in the DOM

```
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({
        onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
</script>
```